# GitHub repository based dependency restore issue in Flutter using Pub get command

Tags: git, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to restore flutter dependency using `flutter pub get` command. My `pubspec.ymal` file has [google_map_location_picker](https://github.com/lyokone/google_map_location_picker) dependency from the github repository. I am using below configuration in the pubspec.ymal file.

[image]

But I am getting git error.

[image]

I cleared **pub-cache** folder as well. But there has not good sign.

Please help me to resolve this configuration issue.

Comment: It's very odd, curious, and *wrong* that `github.com` is resolving to `20.205.243.166` as the latter is a Microsoft Azure DNS server. It's not GitHub.

Comment: You are right. It seems curious me too. Google says it is Azure DNS. But pubget says it is a github DNS. 
 @torek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the GitHub repos as such now. Either you need to add the ssh key into your system and pass add the password and username info in the URL or simply use the HTTPS URL like below.

```
google_map_location_picker:
    git: https://www.github.com/Lyokone/google_map_location_picker.git
```